# Comparing two columns in postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, comparison

I am somewhat stumped on a seemingly simple problem.  I have a table set up such as,

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
     column_1 TEXT,
     column_2 TEXT);
```

Where the contents of these tables look like

```
column_1  |  column_2
---------------------
Atlanta   |  Atlanta
Boston    |  Chicago
Chicago   |  Los Angeles
Seattle   |  Tacoma
NULL      |  Seattle
```

What query could I run that would look at both of these columns, and despite their order, return where the two columns matchup?

The result I am looking for would be:

```
column_1  |  column_2
---------------------
Atlanta   |  Atlanta
Chicago   |  Chicago
Seattle   |  Seattle
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM cities
WHERE column_1 = column_2;
```

But this only returns the EXACT matches:

```
column_1  |  column_2
---------------------
Atlanta   |  Atlanta
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need a self join:

```
SELECT c1.column_1, c2.column_2
FROM cities c1
JOIN cities c2
    ON c1.column_1 = c2.column_2
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll upvote this as the answer when it lets me (it's giving me an 8 minute timeout).

Answer (score 0):

your query is asking the question where is column_1 == column_2 in the same row.  If you want to retrieve all instances of cities existing in both columns you would need to do a self join like so.

```
SELECT t1.column_1, t2.column_2
FROM cities t1 join cities t2 on (t1.column_1 = t2.column_2)
```